# Can i deploy spring restful webapplication in node

Tags: node.js

is it possible to deploy spring rest application in node / node server.

I have a spring rest application where there are many endpoints.

As far as i understood node is lightweight. so can i deploy the application in node. If so, how to do it.

Comment: spring is java - node is JS -

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't.

You are comparing apples with oranges.

A Spring app is deployed inside a **Java** runtime.

Node.js is a **Javascript** runtime, a way to run Javascript code outside of the browser.

You cannot deploy Java applications inside a Javascript runtime.

Regarding the performance of a Java vs Javascript backend the answer is not straight forward.
It depends on the framework/libraries you are using and how you write the application code.